# PyQt5 Pop-out window error: QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout, which already has a layout

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 GUI application and I am trying to create a pop-out window. I have created a class `sideWindow` which is called by a button on the main window. The code works fine the first time the `sideWindow` is called from the main GUI window. However, if I close the `sideWindow` and reopen I get the error and the format of the window is messed up:

`QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on sideWindow "", which already has a layout`

I assume from this that because the layout has already been set on the first time of opening, it doesn't need to be set again. However, I'm not sure which bit of the `sideWindow` class I need to change to avoid this error. I've tried setting `clearLayout` in the `sideWindow` class but that didn't help.

```
class sideWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.viewer = parent

    def initiateMenuBar(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Phasing')
        self.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        MenuBar = QVBoxLayout()
        self.labels = {
            'phase 0': QLabel('Phase 0', self),
        }
        self.inputs = {
            'phase 0 sl': QSlider(Qt.Horizontal),          
            'phase 0': QDoubleSpinBox(self),
        }

        for i in self.inputs.values():
            i.installEventFilter(self)

        class dividor(QFrame):

            def __init__(self, parent):
                QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
                self.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
                self.setLineWidth(3)
                self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
                self.show()

        self.inputs['phase 0'].valueChanged.connect(self.inputs['phase 0 sl'].setValue)
        self.inputs['phase 0 sl'].valueChanged.connect(self.inputs['phase 0'].setValue)

        MenuBar.addWidget(self.labels['phase 0'])
        MenuBar.addWidget(self.inputs['phase 0'])
        MenuBar.addWidget(self.inputs['phase 0 sl'])
        MenuBar.addWidget(dividor(self))
        MenuBar.addStretch(1)

        self.inputs['phase 0'].setValue(0)

        return MenuBar

    def setupWindow(self):

        MenuBar = self.initiateMenuBar()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)        

        grid.addLayout(MenuBar, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 100)
        self.show()
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You have defined setupWindow method to define and show sideWindow. Define one more method, to show sideWindow after it was defined. You may remove self.show() from setupWindow and call show separately. Then you will call setupWindow only once and show as many times as required.

Comment: This was a really helpful comment, #Sergey, and pointed me towards a solution. I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The key, as suggested by #Sergey is that `setupWindow` is recreating the window each time it is called. As shown below, I have included an `if` statement in `setupWindow`. If the pop-out window has already been defined (i.e. by previously loading) then the widget is identified and only reopened, not recreated. The modified function `setupWindow` is:

```
def setupWindow(self):

    if not self.myWdg:
        self.myWdg = QWidget()

        MenuBar = self.initiateMenuBar()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)        

        grid.addLayout(MenuBar, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.myWdg.setLayout(grid)
        self.myWdg.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 100)

    self.myWdg.show()
    self.myWdg.activateWindow()
```

A full MWE for this question is shown below. This creates a small GUI window ('Main') with a button which opens a second window 'Phasing' containing a `QSpinBox`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QDoubleSpinBox,\
    QLabel


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        button = QPushButton('Button', self)
        button.move(50, 50) 

        self.sideWindowTest = sideWindowTest(self)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.sideWindowTest.setupWindow())

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main')

        self.show()

class sideWindowTest(object):

    myWdg = None

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.viewer = parent

    def initiateMenuBar(self):
        self.myWdg.setWindowTitle('Phasing')
        self.myWdg.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        MenuBar = QVBoxLayout()
        self.labels = {
            'phase 0': QLabel('Phase 0', self.myWdg),
        }
        self.inputs = {
            'phase 0': QDoubleSpinBox(self.myWdg),
        }

        for i in self.inputs.values():
            i.installEventFilter(self.myWdg)

        self.inputs['phase 0'].setValue(0)

        MenuBar.addWidget(self.labels['phase 0'])
        MenuBar.addWidget(self.inputs['phase 0'])
        MenuBar.addStretch(1)

        return MenuBar

    def setupWindow(self):

        if not self.myWdg:
            self.myWdg = QWidget()

            MenuBar = self.initiateMenuBar()

            grid = QGridLayout()
            grid.setSpacing(10)        

            grid.addLayout(MenuBar, 0, 0, 1, 2)
            self.myWdg.setLayout(grid)
            self.myWdg.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 100)

        self.myWdg.show()
        self.myWdg.activateWindow() 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```